# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT returned duplicated values. Can't use DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, group-concat

I'm making a query using 5 tables, connecting them using `LEFT JOIN` and grouping some results with `GROUP_CONCAT`.

The problem is that the `GROUP_CONCAT` results is duplicating in this columns:

```
pedido_lentes
pedidos_lente_quantidades
pedidos_lente_solares
pedido_armacoes
pedidos_armacao_codigos
pedidos_armacao_tipos
```

Here is the SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/efc27e/2

Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
pedidos.id_pedido AS id_pedido, lentes, armacao, pedidos.observacao AS observacao, 
valor, pagamento, sinal, parcelas, restante, tipo_pagamento, forma_pagamento, DATE_FORMAT(data, "%e/%m/%Y - %H:%i:%s") AS data, entrega, 
vendedor_pedidos, agendar_servico, 

receitas.receita AS receita,

GROUP_CONCAT(lentes.nome) AS pedido_lentes,
GROUP_CONCAT(pedidos_lentes.quantidade) AS pedidos_lente_quantidades,
GROUP_CONCAT(pedidos_lentes.solar) AS pedidos_lente_solares,

GROUP_CONCAT(armacoes.nome) AS pedido_armacoes,
GROUP_CONCAT(pedidos_armacoes.codigo) AS pedidos_armacao_codigos,
GROUP_CONCAT(pedidos_armacoes.tipo) AS pedidos_armacao_tipos

FROM pedidos 
JOIN receitas ON receitas.id_receita = pedidos.id_receita 

LEFT JOIN pedidos_lentes ON pedidos_lentes.id_pedido = pedidos.id_pedido
LEFT JOIN lentes ON lentes.id_lente = pedidos_lentes.id_lente

left JOIN pedidos_armacoes ON pedidos_armacoes.id_pedido = pedidos.id_pedido
left JOIN armacoes ON armacoes.id_armacao = pedidos_armacoes.id_armacao

WHERE pedidos.id_cliente = 5353 
GROUP BY pedidos.id_pedido
ORDER BY pedidos.data DESC
```

What I expect:

```
    | id_pedido |         lentes |          armacao | observacao |  valor | pagamento |  sinal | parcelas | restante | tipo_pagamento | forma_pagamento |                  data | entrega | vendedor_pedidos | agendar_servico |    receita |                                                         pedido_lentes | pedidos_lente_quantidades | pedidos_lente_solares |               pedido_armacoes | pedidos_armacao_codigos | pedidos_armacao_tipos |
    |-----------|----------------|------------------|------------|--------|-----------|--------|----------|----------|----------------|-----------------|-----------------------|---------|------------------|-----------------|------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|---------------------------|-----------------------|-------------------------------|-------------------------|-----------------------|
    |      9561 |         (null) |           (null) |      Teste |  20,00 |   à vista |        |        0 |          |       efetuado |        dinheiro | 15/02/2016 - 13:12:05 |  avisar |        webmaster |          (null) | 24/12/2014 | Orma Crizal Easy,Orma Crizal Forte |                 10,3 |               1,0,1,0 | Flair,Blacktop |               2,33 |               1,1 |
    |      7448 | teste de lente | teste de armação |            | 200,00 | parcelado | 100,00 |       10 |    10,00 |     na entrega |            Visa |  8/04/2015 - 11:07:36 |  avisar |        webmaster |          (null) | 24/12/2014 |                                                                (null) |                    (null) |                (null) |                        (null) |                  (null) |                (null) |
```

Comment: Please copy your queries and data to the site

Comment: Why can't you use `DISTINCT`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Because the numbers of values in the columns listed above need to be equal.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is duplicating"?  It would be extremely helpful if you gave information on your table schema, sample data, the results set you are getting and the result set you are trying to get.

Comment: So what would be the desired output for your sample query for those fields? For example, `pedidos_armacao_tipos` has only one distinct value, should it give `1,1`? What would in that case be the desired output if one has 3 and one has 4 distinct values? 12 values in all fields since that's the only way to duplicate all fields the same number of times and end up even...?

Comment: @MikeBrant In pedidos_lentes column, there are four values (Orma Crizal Easy,Orma Crizal Forte,Orma Crizal Easy,Orma Crizal Forte), but the correct is only two (Orma Crizal Easy,Orma Crizal Forte). The same error occours in the columns listed above.

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` is an option in `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT lentes.nome) AS pedido_lentes,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pedidos_lentes.quantidade) AS pedidos_lente_quantidades,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pedidos_lentes.solar) AS pedidos_lente_solares,

GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT armacoes.nome) AS pedido_armacoes,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pedidos_armacoes.codigo) AS pedidos_armacao_codigos,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pedidos_armacoes.tipo) AS pedidos_armacao_tipos
```

Although often the simplest way to resolve these problems, it does indicate that a Cartesian product is happening due to the joins.  Often, it is more efficient to pre-aggregate the data before doing the joins.

Comment: As far as I understand it, that does not solve `"Because the numbers of values in the columns listed above need to be equal"` from the comments.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson . . . Actually, as I understand the question and comments, `DISTINCT` is exactly what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to include some qualifiers inside your `GROUP_CONCAT()` aggregator function.

You can say, for example,

```
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT lentes.nome ORDER BY lentes.id_lente) AS pedido_lentes
```

That will remove the duplicate `nome` values from that result, and order them predictably.  Check it out.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/efc27e/4/0

Note well: You are misusing the evil nonstandard MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`. That may be part of your trouble.  Please read this.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: As far as I understand it, that does not solve "Because the numbers of values in the columns listed above need to be equal" from the comments.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Correct.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
SELECT 
pedidos.id_pedido AS id_pedido, lentes, armacao, pedidos.observacao AS observacao, 
valor, pagamento, sinal, parcelas, restante, tipo_pagamento, forma_pagamento, DATE_FORMAT(data, "%e/%m/%Y - %H:%i:%s") AS data, entrega, 
vendedor_pedidos, agendar_servico, 

receitas.receita AS receita,

lentes1.pedido_lentes,
lentes1.pedidos_lente_quantidades,
lentes1.pedidos_lente_solares,

armacoes1.pedido_armacoes,
armacoes1.pedidos_armacao_codigos,
armacoes1.pedidos_armacao_tipos

FROM pedidos 
JOIN receitas ON receitas.id_receita = pedidos.id_receita 


LEFT JOIN (
SELECT
id_pedido,
GROUP_CONCAT(lentes.nome) AS pedido_lentes,
GROUP_CONCAT(pedidos_lentes.quantidade) AS pedidos_lente_quantidades,
GROUP_CONCAT(pedidos_lentes.solar) AS pedidos_lente_solares
FROM pedidos_lentes
JOIN lentes ON lentes.id_lente = pedidos_lentes.id_lente
GROUP BY pedidos_lentes.id_pedido
) lentes1 ON pedidos.id_pedido = lentes1.id_pedido

LEFT JOIN(
SELECT
id_pedido,
GROUP_CONCAT(armacoes.nome) AS pedido_armacoes,
GROUP_CONCAT(pedidos_armacoes.codigo) AS pedidos_armacao_codigos,
GROUP_CONCAT(pedidos_armacoes.tipo) AS pedidos_armacao_tipos
FROM pedidos_armacoes
JOIN armacoes ON armacoes.id_armacao = pedidos_armacoes.id_armacao
GROUP BY pedidos_armacoes.id_pedido
) armacoes1 ON pedidos.id_pedido = armacoes1.id_pedido

WHERE pedidos.id_cliente = 5353 
GROUP BY pedidos.id_pedido
ORDER BY pedidos.data DESC
```